# Additional Subnet IPs for Hyper-v VM- VSwitches

Tags: networking, virtual-machine, ip, hyper-v, subnet

i recently bought a dedi server from hetzner to use with hyper-v VMs, for the first 6 additional IPs hyper-v worked fine with default(auto) Virtual switch, i just created VMs, attached unique mac addresses from hetzner panel(by generating).. but after 7th VM i had to buy additional subnet(instead of IP) additional subnet includes 6 usable IPs, now with those new IPs i dont have option to generate MAC addresses, i followed all guides on the internet but failed and really confused, tried their https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/windows-server/windows-server-subnet too but no result. Some how internet showing working after adding manually IP,gateway on the VM and newly created Switch, but unable to use internet and unable to connect Via RDP connection.

i am not that technical person so i need help in that case. if anyone? as hetzner don't provide software support.

Thanks.

Comment: How many IPs are you allowed?  Your subnet mask will limit you to a specific number. i.e, if you have a /29 mask, then you're limited.

Comment: 6 usable allowed. and i wanted to use that 6 not more than that. and yes /29 they're.